# Is it possible to copy data from a texture 2D (GL_TEXTURE_2D) to an array buffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER)?

Tags: c, opengl, vertex, texture2d, vertex-buffer

I am developing a program, which can calculate histogram on GPU. I'm using OpenGL to write code. In first step, I load value of pixel (RGB) to an array (`arr_image`) and upload it to Vertex buffer (`vbo`):

```
GLuint vbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

GLuint num_input_data = width * height;

/* Upload data */
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, num_input_data * sizeof(float) * 3, arr_image, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

And it's working, I can calculate histogram of image.

But now, I want load data from a texture (`GL_TEXTURE_2D`) (as results of my previous steps) to Array Buffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER). Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if your overall approach is really the best way to go, but I'm going to address only your specific question here:

A buffer object in OpenGL can be bound to every buffer target. To copy pixel data from a texture into a buffer object, you can just bind your buffer to `GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER` which means using it as a [*Pixel Buffer Object* (*PBO*)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object). When a PBO is bound, any operation reading back pixel data from the GL will write the data into the PBO. So you can issue a [`glGetTexImage`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetTexImage.xhtml) call. Just like with VBOs, the `pixels` pointer of these calls is now interpreted not as a client memory address, but an offset into the PBO.

You can then bind this buffer to the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` target and use it as a source for vertex data.